# Send message and shortly delete it

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord bot delete its "system messages" after, say, 10 seconds, because I've been seeing a lot of "Invalid command" errors and "Done!" notifications, and I'd like to clear them out for actual messages. This is different from deleting messages where the user has a command; I already have that capability.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The bot uses ``message.channel.send(text)`` for all its sent messages. I don't know where to start.

Comment: @HarutheBishie did LW001's answer below work for you? If so, please mark it as correct. If not, please explain what else you are looking for.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I recommend you send the message, wait for the response and delete the returned message after that time. Here's how it'd work now:

```
message.reply('Invalid command')
  .then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000)
  })
  .catch(/*Your Error handling if the Message isn't returned, sent, etc.*/);
```

See [the Discord.JS Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) for more information about the `Message.delete()` function and the [Node Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) for information about `setTimeout()`.

**Old** ways to do this were:

Discord.JS [v12](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message?scrollTo=delete):

```
message.reply('Invalid command')
  .then(msg => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 })
  })
  .catch(/*Your Error handling if the Message isn't returned, sent, etc.*/);
```

Discord.JS [v11](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Message?scrollTo=delete):

```
message.reply('Invalid command')
  .then(msg => {
    msg.delete(10000)
  })
  .catch(/*Your Error handling if the Message isn't returned, sent, etc.*/);
```

Comment: if you're using discord.js v12 (master branch currently) you will need to change `msg.delete(10000)` to `msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 })`

Comment: Now deprecated. Please use `setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000)`

Comment: As this is still active, I've updated the answer to the way to do it on the current master branch (v13).

Answer (score 20):

Current API differs from older versions. Proper way to pass timeout looks like this now.

Discord.js v13

```
message.reply('Invalid command!')
  .then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000)
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Discord.js v12

```
message.reply('Invalid command!')
  .then(msg => {
    msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 })
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Every Discord.JS Version has a new way to delete with timeout.**

Discord.JS V11:

```
message.channel.send('Test!').then(msg => msg.delete(10000));
```

Discord.JS V12:

```
message.channel.send('Test!').then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 10000}));
```

Discord.JS V13:

```
message.channel.send('Test!').then(msg => setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 10000));
```

Time is in milliseconds