# Delete message short after sending it Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I saw the question [Send message and shortly delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907207/send-message-and-shortly-delete-it), but it the answer uses message.reply which I don't want to.

So I want to send a message and after 5000 ms delete it, but message.channel.send doesn't return a `Message`so I can delete it. Is there any send function that returns a `Message`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send message and shortly delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907207/send-message-and-shortly-delete-it)

Comment: Read the question...

Comment: The comment was automatically generated when I flagged this question as a duplicate. I left an answer explaining why the question you linked does, in fact, answer your question too. `message.channel.send` *does* resolve with a Message, if you're having a hard time getting one out of it, then I suggest asking a question showing your code so answerers can diagnose what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.channel.send()` returns a `Promise<Message>`, just like `message.reply()`. The reply method simply defers to `message.channel.send()` internally, prepending a mention of the author.

Try it: Use the exact code in the answer to the question you linked. Replace `.reply()` with `.channel.send()`.

Comment: That was awkward. The reason I didn't see this was because it returns `Promise<Message | Message[]>` and it just showed me `.toString()`. Thanks for your answer. ;)